# How can i solve this Undefined index:?

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

**How can I solve this error? I have to try anything, but the result is the same error. Please help me to solve this problem error**

```
[My error][1]
```

***And this is my Code in update.php:***

```
    <?php
include_once 'config.php';

$employee_id=$_GET['employee_id'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$date_of_birth=$_POST['date_of_birth'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$marital_status=$_POST['marital_status'];
$nationality=$_POST['nationality'];
$present_address=$_POST['present_address'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$nip=$_POST['nip'];
$status=$_POST['status'];
$designation=$_POST['designation'];
$joining_date=$_POST['joining_date'];
$leaving_date=$_POST['leaving_date'];
$picture = basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);

if (!empty($_FILES['picture'])) {   
    $path = "admin/gambar/";
    $path = $path . basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['picture']['name']) .
        " has been uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again";
    }
}

$query = "UPDATE employee_list set name='$name', date_of_birth='$date_of_birth', gender='$gender', marital_status='$marital_status', nationality='$nationality', present_address='$present_address', city='$city', country='$country', phone='$phone', email='$email', nip=$nip, status='$status', designation='$designation', joining_date='$joining_date', leaving_date='$leaving_date', picture='$picture' where employee_id=$employee_id";
?>


Thank you :)
```

Comment: each field set null value

Comment: employee_id=' ';

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` gives what? You are open to SQL injections. Parameterize the query.

Comment: This question is liable to **downvotes** as posting links to images of your code is considered disruptive formatting and makes code very hard to reproduce. Also, please don't echo what you are stating.

Comment: sorry,  I'm still learning

Comment: can you explain again with the specific answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `isset()` to avoid these errors. something like given below.

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
if (isset($_POST['employee_id'])) {

$employee_id=$_POST['employee_id'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$date_of_birth=$_POST['date_of_birth'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$marital_status=$_POST['marital_status'];
$nationality=$_POST['nationality'];
$present_address=$_POST['present_address'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$nip=$_POST['nip'];
$status=$_POST['status'];
$designation=$_POST['designation'];
$joining_date=$_POST['joining_date'];
$leaving_date=$_POST['leaving_date'];
$picture = basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);

if (!empty($_FILES['picture'])) {   
    $path = "admin/gambar/";
    $path = $path . basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['picture']['name']) .
        " has been uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again";
    }
}

$query = "UPDATE employee_list set name='$name', date_of_birth='$date_of_birth', gender='$gender', marital_status='$marital_status', nationality='$nationality', present_address='$present_address', city='$city', country='$country', phone='$phone', email='$email', nip=$nip, status='$status', designation='$designation', joining_date='$joining_date', leaving_date='$leaving_date', picture='$picture' where employee_id=$employee_id";
}
?>
```

> Note:Use prepared query to avoid sql injection attack.

Comment: update your question with the code, not image then I will help you properly.

Comment: you need to paste the update.php code  inside given method

Comment: I made it.Please help me

Comment: ping me on given link

Comment: sorry..this is make same error.
if (isset($_GET['employee_id'])) {
   //paste the php code here
}

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176455/rahul .click on this link and ping me

Comment: I can't ping you. I don't have the reputation

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

put all your code from line #4 to end of the file in following if statement

```
if (!empty($_GET['employee_id'])) {

    // your code 
}
```

also, your code is not secure for SQL injection, XSS, CSRF attacks. You can use http://csrf.htmlpurifier.org/ library to protect your code against CSRF attacks.

Use PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to protect SQL injection.